# Boost::ASIO: using tcp::socket on multiple threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, tcp, boost-asio

So I have a `TCP` server that waits on a specific port for clients to be connected.

If there's one client connection, I construct a `tcp::socket` object with some `asio::io_service`, then I accept that socket. Example:

```
void Gateway::server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, unsigned short port) {
    tcp::acceptor a(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port));
    bool UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted = false;

    for (;;) {
        tcp::socket sock(io_service);

        a.accept(sock);

        std::thread(startWiFiToUARTSession, std::move(sock)).detach();

        if(false == UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted) {
            //std::thread(startUARTToWifiSession, std::move(sock2)).detach();
            UARTToWiFiGatewayStarted = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to use this socket's functionality on at least two threads, one thread will read (blocking) from the socket (`read_some(...)`), and the other thread needs to write (blocking) data using that socket.

I was trying to construct two `tcp::socket` objects using the same `asio::io_service` object but that won't work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by "won't work"?

Comment: "use this socket's functionality on at least two threads" -- you mean that same connection to a single client?

Comment: Each `tcp::socket` object should refer to a discrete native socket.  Can you please explain the motivation for wanting to use two `tcp::socket` objects for a single TCP connection?

Comment: @TannerSansbury I want two `tcp::socket` to refer to the same discrete native socket. I want this because I can't share the existing one between two threads.

Comment: @DanMašek Yes, I basically have two worker threads: form one thread I want to read something from the connected client, and from the other thread I want to be able to write something to the same client.

Comment: @Xirema I can't remember the exact behavior right now, I will come back with more details.

Comment: @Marius Why can you not share a single `tcp::socket` object between two threads via reference, `shared_ptr`, etc?  The `tcp::socket` object is designed to take ownership of the native socket.  Having two `tcp::socket` objects claiming ownership of the same native socket may add unnecessary complexity.

Comment: IMHO I'd just go for one thread for `io_service::run()` and use async reads/writes.

Comment: @TannerSansbury Because they're not thread safe, so I won't be able to simultaneously `write()` and/or `read()` from both worker threads.

Comment: Can I use the same instance of boost::asio::io_service for all my sockets in multithreading? Same question for boost::asio::ssl::context also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket.html) object is designed to take ownership of the native socket and provides [RAII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) semantics for managing the native socket.  Hence, individual `socket` objects should refer to discrete native sockets.  Otherwise, the state of the underlying socket may unexpectedly change.

While the `socket` documentation specifies that making concurrent calls on a single shared `socket` is unsafe, the [revision history](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/history.html#boost_asio.history.asio_1_4_0___boost_1_37) documents an exception to this rule.  As of Asio 1.4.0 / Boost 1.37, if supported by the OS, *synchronous* read, write, accept, and connection operations that are made concurrently on a `socket` object are thread safe:

> **Asio 1.4.0 / Boost 1.37**
>
> - ...
> - Synchronous read, write, accept and connect operations are now thread safe (meaning that it is now permitted to perform concurrent synchronous operations on an individual socket, if supported by the OS).
> - ...

In this case, if supported by the OS, it is thread safe to synchronously read from a socket in one thread, and synchronously write to the same socket concurrently in another thread.